Баги в Visual Studio 2022
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-разрядная версия) - Current Версия 17.9.5
Window 10 Pro 10.0.19045 Сборка 19045

Работал в WPF проекте с WritableBitmap, брал source из элемента Image и вставлял пиксели через WritePixels. После срабатывания WritePixels - Image визуально оставался пустым, хотя по отладке все в порядке, и сохраненное изображение в файл подтверждало что все в порядке.
Очень долго пытался понять, в чем же дело. Пока студия не сошла с ума и не выдала ошибки об отсутствии всех элементов управления на форме.
Сделал перезагрузку проекта, интерфейс вернулся в норму, и ошибка с отображением Image пропала также... Уже не первый раз сталкиваюсь с ошибками в студии и сейчас просто в отчаянии... Потерять 3 часа на "ничего".
Может кто посоветует что? Сменить ОС, или переходить на другую среду разработки?

Проблема решилась перезагрузкой проекта, при чем тут ошибки в коде?
